# Findbugs - handling null check and encoding in reading input stream

Tags: java, encoding, null, findbugs

I added Findbugs plugin to my project and I suddenly started getting the following bug: `Dereference of the result of readLine() without nullcheck`

I have the following code which reads the http request line by line:

```
InputStream input = clientSocket.getInputStream();

String line;
while (!(line = in.readLine()).equals("")) {
...
}
```

I tried rewriting this into some other for with nullcheck:

```
String line = "";
while (line != null) {
    line = in.readLine();

  if (line.equals("")) return;
}
```

But this gets stuck forever (so it is not rewritten correctly). I am sorry for such a basic question but I can't seem to get it right...

Another thing that is marked as bug is `Found reliance on default encoding in ..InputStream...`

How can I specify encoding in InputStreamReader?

Comment: is there a particular reason you return with an empty string? just trying to parse the http headers? readLine() will return null, not the empty string, when input ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed loop looks like so:

```
InputStream input = clientSocket.getInputStream();

String line;
while (null != (line = in.readLine())) {
    if("".equals(line)) break;
    ...
}
```

Why? First of all, of the remote side (the client) closes the connection, `readLine()` will return `null`. That what the outer check guards against.

`readLine()` won't return at all if the client just stops sending data. So as long as the client keeps the connection open, your "fixed" loop hangs.

When comparing string literals, I always put them first:

```
"".equals(line))
```

never fails, even when `line` is `null`. It's also often more readable since you often want to know what you're comparing against; the variable which you want to check is less "informative".

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `readLine` can return `null`, so you have to check it after the `line = in.readLine();`

Your updated code could still throw a `NullPointerException`, if `readLine` returned `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your change will work, since the check is being made on the *previous* value of line, thus, if your previous line was valid (but you where reading the last line) any subsequent calls can potentially yield a `NullPointerException`.

The go around this, usually the following pattern is applied:

```
InputStream input = clientSocket.getInputStream();

String line = "";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The line `String line = "";` does not look well for me. I prefer `String line;` because empty string in not used anywhere.

Comment: @michaldo: The problem with your approach is that doing `String line;` can potentially lead `NullPointerExcetpions` further down the line should you do operations on the string. Assigning it to empty is one way of going around this problem.